# Complex Region using Presentations Package

Tags: plotting, packages, commercial-package

Just purchased the Presentations package. First sketched this region:

```
<< Presentations`

Draw2D[
 {Opacity[0.6],
  ComplexRegionDraw[0 <= Re[z] <= 1, {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}]},
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> True,
 PlotRange -> 2,
 FrameLabel -> {Re, Im},
 PlotLabel -> z,
 ImageSize -> 300
 ]
```

And I got the image I wanted.

[image: today]

Next, I want to sketch the image of this region under the exponential function $w=e^z$. I tried this:

```
Draw2D[
 {Opacity[0.6],
  ComplexRegionDraw[Exp[z], {z, -2 I, 1 + 2 I}]},
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> True,
 PlotRange -> 2,
 FrameLabel -> {Re, Im},
 PlotLabel -> z,
 ImageSize -> 300
 ]
```

But I got a blank image. Any suggestions?

Looks like I might have an idea.

```
f[z_] := Exp[z]

Draw2D[
 {Opacity[0.6],
  ComplexRegionDraw[0 <= Re[z] <= 1, {z, -2 - 2 I, 1 + 2 I},
    PlotPoints -> 30] // ComplexMap[f]},
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> True,
 PlotRange -> All,
 FrameLabel -> {Re, Im},
 PlotLabel -> z,
 ImageSize -> 300
 ]
```

And the resulting image:

[image: today2]

Of course, what I really wanted was the image of the the strip with $0\le Re[z]\le1$ and $\infty\le Im[z]\le \infty$.

```
Draw2D[
 {Opacity[0.6],
  ComplexRegionDraw[0 <= Re[z] <= 1, {z, 0, 1 + 2 Pi I},
    PlotPoints -> 30] // ComplexMap[f]},
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> True,
 PlotRange -> All,
 FrameLabel -> {Re, Im},
 PlotLabel -> z,
 ImageSize -> 300
 ]
```

And the resulting image.

[image: today3]

Comment: I don't have the package (heard only good things about it!) but from looking at your syntax my guess would be:  the first argument in `ComplexRegionDraw[Exp[z]...` has to be a boolean condition, not a complex function. Therefore, you should replace that by `Abs[Exp[z]]<1`, or `Re[Exp[z]]>0`, or some condition along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

I think you really want $-\pi\leq \Im(z) \leq \pi$. Then let the *Presentations* function `ComplexMap` do the work for you!

```
<< Presentations`

strip = ComplexRegionDraw[0 <= Re[z] <= 1, {z, -2 - Pi I, 2 + 4 Pi I}];
domain = Draw2D[{Opacity[0.6], strip}, 
           Frame->True, Axes->True, PlotRange->2, FrameLabel->{Re, Im}, PlotLabel->z];
image = Draw2D[{Opacity[0.6], strip // ComplexMap[Exp]}, 
           Frame->True, Axes->True,PlotRange->4, FrameLabel->{Re, Im}, PlotLabel->w];
GraphicsRow[{domain, image}, PlotLabel -> "Mapping vertical strip by exp"]
```

Note the use of `ComplexMap[Exp]` in the definition of `image`; that's how the image is found.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice! And it shows me how to write good code. Thanks.

Comment: Question: I notice a lot of people paste their Row image. How do you copy that image so that you can import it to this site?

Comment: I finding this a very helpful introduction to the Complex part of the Presentations package: http://www.mathematica-journal.com/data/uploads/2011/10/EisenbergPark.pdf

Comment: @David, for the row image, first I had downloaded and installed the "SE Uploader" palette from this site -- search the "meta" items from the link at the top of this page for the palette -- then highlighted the entire graphic row, clicked a button on that palette to upload the image (which also places the URL of the upload onto the clipboard), then pasted that URL into my answer here; the image appears!

Comment: Of course I have been using the ComplexGraphics part of *Presentations* to handle complex regions and more general plotting about complex functions. But I even find it expedient to use the ComplexGraphics routines to construct plane figures having nothing explicit to do with complex numbers. Thus if I have to use a bunch of `{x, y}` points, I find it often easier to write them in `x + I y` form and use that form in the graphics code.